# Node server not running Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905   throw err;   
^ Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\akhilesh.raturi\node\firs.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
{ code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',   requireStack: [] }
```

Comment: Well, does the file `C:\Users\akhilesh.raturi\node\firs.js` exist?

Comment: yes it exists !!

Comment: Then use Process Monitor (Google it), set the filter to path ending with `firs.js` and check if node really accesses this path or its getting redirected somehow (it may be sandboxed for instance).

Comment: probably you are running from wrong directory

Comment: post your code also which is raising error

Answer (score 0):

So the problem resolved, I just changed the location of the file and the program is running successfully. Thank you all

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).